# Azure Cross Directory Data Access

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, disaster-recovery

I'm currently developing a Azure solution for one of my managed service clients.
we are developing a power bi service for their Azure backup/ azure recovery.
we are looking to host the whole process in our own azure environment, however we cannot get the data from A) their recovery vault logs into B) our Azure environment.

Anyone have any ideas on how to move data from their environment into our environment storage?
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power BI based reporting gets the data from storage accounts which store Azure Backup data. Once customer configured diagnostic settings to send data to a storage account(ask him to create a dedicated storage account for this), he can share the access keys with you so that you can connect to customer's storage account to get the required data and run Power Bi report in your environment. 
[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-configure-reports) doc has all the details -  with the change being in this case, customer will store data in his storage account and provide you access to that storage account via access key.